# Why does my answer to the integral of $\frac{x^2}{x^2+9}$ need to be multiplied by $3$

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

This is my work below, the answer to the problem was $3$ times what my solution was. Why?

[image: Solution]

The integral was the indefinite integral of $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2}{x^2+9}$ and my answer was $\frac{x}{3}-\arctan(\frac{x}{3})+C$ and the correct answer was $x-3\arctan(\frac{x}{2})+C$.

Comment: If $x=3\tan \theta$ then $dx=3\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$. You missed the factor $3$ here.

Comment: in the last line: "..... and the correct answer was ....", check the denominator of the argument of the arctan. I believe it is $3$ not $2$.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Next time you are taking a picture of some equations and pasting it here if the quality is not that good, consider using https://mathpix.com/ . Just a tip!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to integrate, then you will see easily why it is multiplied by $3$:

Given $\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+9}dx$, now add and subtract $9$ in the numerator, it becomes:

$$\int \frac{(x^2+9)-9}{x^2+9}dx=\int(1-\frac{9}{x^2+9})dx=\int dx-9 \int \frac{1}{x^2+9}dx$$

Recall that $\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+C$

Therefore,

$$\int dx-9 \int \frac{1}{x^2+9}dx=x-9(\frac{1}{3}) \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{3})+C=x-3 \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{3})+C$$

See the last line, the $9$ and the $3$ got simplified.